# Generate XML file with subnodes from xsd file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a xsd file acount.xsd, using which i created a acount.cs file, using this i created a xml file. I have written these following command in c# for button click to generate the xml file.

```
string PATH = "C:\\Sample.xml";
CreateEmptyFile(PATH);
var data = new AutoCount();
data.Product = "AutoCount Accounting";
data.Version = "1.5";
data.CreatedApplication = "BApp";
data.CreatedBy = "Business Solutions";
data.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AutoCount));
using (var stream = new StreamWriter(PATH))
    serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
```

Output XML file was :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoCount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.autocountsoft.com/ac_accounting.xsd">
  <Product>AutoCount Accounting</Product>
  <Version>1.5</Version>
  <CreatedApplication>BApp</CreatedApplication>
  <CreatedBy>Business Solutions</CreatedBy>
</AutoCount>
```

I need a xml file while has sub classes, like
Output XML file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoCount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.autocountsoft.com/ac_accounting.xsd">
  <Product>AutoCount Accounting</Product>
  <Version>1.5</Version>
  <CreatedApplication>BApp</CreatedApplication>
  <CreatedBy>Business Solutions</CreatedBy>
  <Sales DocNo = 'S0001'>
    <Item>XXX</Item>
    <Qty>2</Qty>
    <Price>6.00</Price>
  </Sales>
</AutoCount>
```

To Achieve it i tried this following C# command, but error occurs (have specified it) How do i achieve the above result?

```
string PATH = "C:\\Sample.xml";
CreateEmptyFile(PATH);
var sales = new SalesInvoice();
sales.DocNo = "S0001";
sales.Item = "XXX";
sales.Qty= "2";
sales.Price= "6.00";
var data = new AutoCount();
data.Product = "AutoCount Accounting";
data.Version = "1.5";
data.CreatedApplication = "BApp";
data.CreatedBy = "Business Solutions";
data.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
data.SalesInvoice = sales; /*Error:  Cannot implicitly convert SalesInvoice to SalesInvoice[] */
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AutoCount));
using (var stream = new StreamWriter(PATH))
    serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
```

Comment: "*error occurs (have specified it)*": it seems you didn't provide the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.SalesInvoice = new [] { sales };
```

As the error message states you need to provide an array of SalesInvoice objects.

Comment: Thankyou so much @nimeshjm. It worked. Can you tell me how do i pass database value for salesinvoice, so that if there are two rows result from database, then salesinvoice tag occurs twice with different values

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, where are the different values being stored?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the strings for nodes i am trying to get the strings from database  and write something like this
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {   var sales = new SalesInvoice();data.SalesInvoice = new[] { sales };  sales.DocNo = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
                sales.Item = DateTime.Now;
                sales.Qty = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(); sales.Price = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString();var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SalesInvoice)); }

Comment: I thought my answer would be something like this,
<Sales DocNo = 'S0001'>
    <Item>XXX</Item>
    <Qty>2</Qty>
    <Price>6.00</Price>
  </Sales>
<Sales DocNo = 'S0002'>
    <Item>YYY</Item>
    <Qty>4</Qty>
    <Price>12.00</Price>
  </Sales>
if the datagrid has two rows.

Comment: Can you open a new separate question? It feels like it is a different problem.

Comment: ., i have posted the new question in this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010952/to-pass-more-than-one-row-value-from-database-to-xml