# To pass more than one row value from database to XML

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I want to generate an xml file in the fllowing format.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <AutoCount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.autocountsoft.com/ac_accounting.xsd">
      <Product>AutoCount Accounting</Product>
      <Version>1.5</Version>
      <CreatedApplication>BApp</CreatedApplication>
      <CreatedBy>Business Solutions</CreatedBy>
      <Sales DocNo = 'S0001'>
      <Item>XXX</Item>
      <Qty>2</Qty>
      <Price>6.00</Price>
      </Sales>
      <Sales DocNo = 'S0002'>
      <Item>YYY</Item>
      <Qty>3</Qty>
      <Price>50.00</Price>
      </Sales>
      </AutoCount>
```

I have a grid with four columns Docno,item,qty,price and two rows of data.
but i get only one sales node with last row data in grid.

Code i tried is as follows,

```
        string PATH = "C:\\Samplex.xml";
        CreateEmptyFile(PATH);

        var data = new AutoCount();
        data.Product = "AutoCount Accounting";
        data.Version = "1.5";
        data.CreatedApplication = "BApp";
        data.CreatedBy = "Business Solutions";
        data.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++) 
    {
        var sales = new SalesInvoice();
        data.SalesInvoice = new[] { sales };
        sales.DocNo = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(); 
        sales.Item = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
        sales.Qty = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString(); 
        sales.Price = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString();
        var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SalesInvoice)); 
    }
      var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AutoCount));
        using (var stream = new StreamWriter(PATH))
        serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
```

Output was:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <AutoCount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.autocountsoft.com/ac_accounting.xsd">
      <Product>AutoCount Accounting</Product>
      <Version>1.5</Version>
      <CreatedApplication>BApp</CreatedApplication>
      <CreatedBy>Business Solutions</CreatedBy>
      <Sales DocNo = 'S0002'>
      <Item>YYY</Item>
      <Qty>3</Qty>
      <Price>50.00</Price>
      </Sales>
      </AutoCount>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other problems, the main one is here:

```
data.SalesInvoice = new[] { sales };
```

You create the SalesInvoice array from scratch at evey cycle loop, instead of creating it before the cycle and adding elements inside it.

Here's how I would do (look at variable names too please):

```
//Plural as it is a list
List<SalesInvoice> salesInvoices = new List<SalesInvoice>();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    //Singular as it is a single element
    var salesInvoice = new SalesInvoice();
    salesInvoice.DocNo = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
    salesInvoice.Item = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
    salesInvoice.Qty = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString();
    salesInvoice.Price = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString();
    salesInvoices.Add(salesInvoice);

    //What's the purpose of the next line?
    var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SalesInvoice));
}

// I pluralized this property name too
data.SalesInvoices = salesInvoices.ToArray();
```

Comment: @Paola, 
My grid has an empty new row at the end. thats y i used rowcount-1.

Comment: Ok. I see that your code is probably incomplete, you declare a serializer1 variable that is never used. How do you actually serialize the object?

Comment: Any feedback from your side?

Comment: i have edited the code on where i used the serializer.(added last three lines)

Comment: the node "data.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;" does not appear in my xml file. datetime.now wont be accepted in xml?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand the question. `DateTime.Now` is a C# expression

Comment: for one node i tried sending datetime.now value. instead of value from datagrid, but when i assign like that the node completely missing in the xml file. "data.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;" this is the line in the above mentioned code i am talking about

Comment: Maybe this problem is worth another question on StackOverflow, it seems to me different to the one we discussed about here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013850/datetime-value-not-accepted-in-xml-through-c-sharp

Answer (score -1):

Use a DataSet/DataTable and the program becomes trivial.  Add two datagridviews to your form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        AutoCount autoCount = new AutoCount();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            autoCount.ds.WriteXml(FILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = autoCount.ds.Tables["AutoCount"];
            dataGridView2.DataSource = autoCount.ds.Tables["Sales"];

        }
        public class AutoCount
        {
            public DataSet ds {get; set;} 


            public AutoCount()
            {
                ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable autoCount = new DataTable("AutoCount");
                ds.Tables.Add(autoCount);
                DataTable sales = new DataTable("Sales");
                ds.Tables.Add(sales);

                autoCount.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
                autoCount.Columns.Add("Version", typeof(string));
                autoCount.Columns.Add("CreatedApplication", typeof(string));
                autoCount.Columns.Add("CreatedBy", typeof(string));
                autoCount.Rows.Add(new string[] {
                    "AutoCount Accounting",
                    "1.5",
                    "BApp",
                    "Business Solutions"
                });

                sales.Columns.Add("DocNo", typeof(string));
                sales.Columns.Add("Item", typeof(string));
                sales.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));
                sales.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(double));

                sales.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    "S0001",
                    "XXX",
                    2,
                    6.00
                });

                sales.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    "S0002",
                    "YYY",
                    3,
                    50.00
                });

            }
        }

    }
}
```