# Datetime value not accepted in XML through c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Unable to pass datetime.now value to a node  'createddatetime'.
Output xml file discards the node. i used the following code,

```
   string PATH = "C:\\Samplex.xml";
    CreateEmptyFile(PATH);

    var data = new AutoCount();
    data.Product = "AutoCount Accounting";
    data.Version = "1.5";
    data.CreatedApplication = "BApp";
    data.CreatedBy = "Business Solutions";
    data.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;   /* this line*/
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AutoCount));
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(PATH))
    serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
```

And the out put was:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <AutoCount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.autocountsoft.com/ac_accounting.xsd">
   <Product>AutoCount Accounting</Product>
    <Version>1.5</Version>
      <CreatedApplication>BApp</CreatedApplication>
       <CreatedBy>Business Solutions</CreatedBy>
    </AutoCount>
```

Instead of :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AutoCount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.autocountsoft.com/ac_accounting.xsd">
   <Product>AutoCount Accounting</Product>
    <Version>1.5</Version>
      <CreatedApplication>BApp</CreatedApplication>
       <CreatedBy>Business Solutions</CreatedBy>
       <CreatedDateTime>2015-05-03 18:01:35</CreatedDateTime>
    </AutoCount>
```

Comment: Can I see the definition of AutoCount class? I did a test and it worked

Comment: As above, show the definition of `AutoCount`.  If it was generated from a schema and the element optional there may be a `CreatedDateTimeSpecified` boolean that you need to set to `true`.

Comment: :) @Charles. Yes it worked thank you. Are you familier with this autocount xsd ?

Comment: Nope, just seen a few class definitions generated by xsd.exe or similar!

Comment: Ok Thank you.. Because i am new to this xml creation with help of xsd and i am struggling to create on full structure. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a class definition is generated by xsd.exe for an optional element (one with `minOccurs="0"`, for example) with a type that maps to a value type such as `DateTime`, an additional property will be generated to indicate whether or not its value should be serialized.

In this case it would seem `CreatedDateTime` is optional, so the related `CreatedDateTimeSpecified` property should be set to `true`:

```
data.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
data.CreatedDateTimeSpecified = true;
```