# To Pass Values for Enum Fields in c# to create xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml, enums, xsd

How do we pass strings to enum fields of a cs file (cs file of xsd file).

I have written the following code,

```
string PATH = "C:\\Sample.xml";
CreateEmptyFile(PATH);

var data = new AutoCount();
data.Product = "AutoCount Accounting";
data.Version = "1.5";
data.CreatedApplication = "BApp";
data.CreatedBy = "Business Solutions";
data.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Today;
data.CreatedDateTimeSpecified = true;
var detail = new SalesIVCSDetailNode();
detail.ItemsElementName = new [] {
    ItemsChoiceType3.ItemCode,
    ItemsChoiceType3.UOM,
    ItemsChoiceType3.Qty,
    ItemsChoiceType3.UnitPrice
};

/* above line */
detail.TaxType = "SR";

List<SalesInvoice> salesInvoices = new List<SalesInvoice>();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++) {
    var salesInvoice = new SalesInvoice();
    salesInvoice.DocNo = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
    salesInvoice.DocDate = DateTime.Today;
    salesInvoice.DebtorCode = "ABC Company";
    salesInvoice.Detail =new [] {detail};
    salesInvoices.Add(salesInvoice);
}

data.SalesInvoice = salesInvoices.ToArray();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AutoCount));
using (var stream = new StreamWriter(PATH))
serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
```

I want the output to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AutoCount xmlns="http://schemas.autocountsoft.com/ac_accounting.xsd">
<Product>AutoCount Accounting</Product>
<Version>1.5</Version>
<CreatedApplication>BApp</CreatedApplication>
<CreatedDateTime>2015-02-23T09:51:54.5746</CreatedDateTime>
<CreatedBy>Business Solutions</CreatedBy>
<SalesInvoice DocNo="IV-0022" ImportAction="AddUpdate">
  <DocDate>2015-02-15</DocDate>
  <DebtorCode>I50201</DebtorCode>
  <Detail>
    <ItemCode>IMP001</ItemCode>
    <UOM>PCS</UOM>
    <Qty>2</Qty>
    <UnitPrice>15.00</UnitPrice>
  </Detail>
</SalesInvoice>
</AutoCount>
```

Problem is i am not aware of how to send strings for enum fields. i dono how to create nodes    .How do we do it?

the line in the c# query.'ItemsChoiceType3' is enum.

```
detail.ItemsElementName = new [] {
    ItemsChoiceType3.ItemCode,
    ItemsChoiceType3.UOM,
    ItemsChoiceType3.Qty,
    ItemsChoiceType3.UnitPrice
};
```

**EDIT:**
The Following is the autocount.cs file taken from autocount.xsd file.
I need help in accessing the itemcode,qty,uom,unitprice tags and passing values to it (hardcoding or database)

```
public partial class SalesIVCSDetailNode
 {
  private object[] itemsField;
  private ItemsChoiceType3[] itemsElementNameField;
  private string locationField;
  private string descriptionField;
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemCode", typeof(string))]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PackageCode", typeof(string))]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Qty", typeof(decimal))]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("UOM", typeof(string))]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("UnitPrice", typeof(decimal))]
         [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
  public object[] Items
  {
     get
     {
        return this.itemsField;
     }
     set
     {
        this.itemsField = value;
     }
  }
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]      
  public ItemsChoiceType3[] ItemsElementName
  {
     get
     {
        return this.itemsElementNameField;
     }
     set
     {
        this.itemsElementNameField = value;
     }
  }    
}


public enum ItemsChoiceType3
{

  ItemCode,

  PackageCode,

  Qty,

  UOM,

  UnitPrice,
}
```

Comment: Duplicate posting.  Gave solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010952/to-pass-more-than-one-row-value-from-database-to-xml

Comment: Kindly read the question fully.

Comment: Did you try my code?  I'm using the WriteSXML method with the WriteSchema option that saves the xsd data embedded in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decorate with XMLEnumAttribute - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute.aspx

Comment: Can You Give an Example on how to send a string?

Comment: public enum ItemsChoiceType3
    {
        [XmlEnum(Name = "IMP001")]
        ItemCode,
        [XmlEnum(Name = "PCS")]
        UOM,
        [XmlEnum(Name = "2")]
        Qty,
        [XmlEnum(Name = "15.00")]
        UnitPrice   
    }
but the better way is to create new class, something like:

class ItemsElementName 
{
   public ItemsChoiceType3 Type {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
}

Comment: how to call it back in above c# code to get the expected result.?
I have the enum class in the cs file generated from xsd file. Should i change that cs file directly? if so by doing that how do we get values in xml file?

Comment: Duplicate.  Gave solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010952/to-pass-more-than-one-row-value-from-database-to-xml